# Chrome devtools change layout of Elements tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have vertical monitor and I want to change the layout of Elements tab.
Is it possible to put Styles sidebar to bottom? Have a look at screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Not really, see https://crbug.com/131894. But you can probably write your own *custom devtools theme* which changes the default width trigger for Styles placement at bottom. Currently it's like 700px or something.

Comment: that is the way mine is right now.  So there must be a way.  It used to be like pictured above, then out of no where it switched.  I hate it, and I cannot figure out how to switch it back

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Click the menu bar in the top right corner.  Goto settings => preferences.  Under the appearance setting there is an option called panel layout which allows you to change the layout.

https://makandracards.com/makandra/41536-how-to-force-horizontal-panel-layout-for-chrome

Answer (score 9):

In Chrome DevTools Tab,
At Top-Right Corner,
Go To Dropdown -> Settings -> Click on Restore Defaults.
It will work..

Comment: Restore defaults just restores the default setting, which is probably "auto". This doesn't answer the question.