# Developer tools - Horizontal Panel - not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, panel, window-resize, google-developer-tools

I cannot get the panel layout to change to horizontal, no matter the width of the devtool panel.

Thank you in advance.
[screen capture of open devtool panel - set to horizontal, but displaying as vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLUE7.jpg)

Comment: The Panel Layout option is for the Styles pane, not DevTools itself. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139524/159145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the DevTools to horizontal layout, use the dock options available in the three dot menu, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The panel layout option in the settings is for the Styles & adjacent panes.